# How to remove error while uploading war file on tomcat server

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, tomcat8

I am using aws and have created an EC2 server. While merging it with a DNS taken from godaddy, now i am not able to upload my WAR file on DNSname:port/manager, not I am able to upload my WAR file on aws [Public DNS (IPv4)]:port/manager.

Getting error while uploading a file showing the following:

This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Comment: After 2 to 3% of uploading it is showing error, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Is the port open from your laptop/desktop or wherever you are uploading from? Can you telnet to the host/port?

Comment: yes, when I was not adding the Route 53 service it was working fine, once I added to route 53 service and linked it with DNS of godaddy problem started to arise.

Comment: I just tested it with my domain and it worked perfectly fine for me. Did you use an Elastic IP or a public IP? If you did not use an Elastic IP and stopped/started your server....your public P might have changed and you need to update your record set accordingly. Are you using a public hosted zone? Are you able to get the manager console page? Did you verify the name servers have been updated correctly on godaddy control panel?